# Passing 3 textbox Values from Gridview into another page using 1 query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass values from my gridview to another form but the problem that i have 3 textboxes with the same column name.. so i need to take the first value to the first textbox and second value to the second textbox..

```
asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit" Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="StdId,Student Name,Gender,Date Of Birth,School,Phone Number1,Email,Start Date"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="NewStd.aspx?StdId={0}&Student Name={1}&Gender={2}&Date Of Birth={3}&School={4}&Phone Number1={5}&Email={6}&Start Date={7}" />
```

Here's th second form page

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["StdId"];
        Label2.Text = id;


        firstxt.Text + midtxt.Text + Lasttext.Text = Request.QueryString["Student Name"]; // error in this code
        Genderdroplist.SelectedValue= Request.QueryString["Gender"];
        DOBTxt.Text = Request.QueryString["Date Of Birth"];
        Schooltxt.Text = Request.QueryString["School"];
        Numbertxt.Text = Request.QueryString["Phone Number1"];
        EmailTxt.Text = Request.QueryString["Email"];
        StartDatetxt.Text = Request.QueryString["Start Date"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the student name by white-spaces to get each part.

The middle name part can be tricky because someone with two middle names can exist.

This code covers all. (No middle names is also ok)

Good luck.

```
string studentName = Request.QueryString["Student Name"];

string[] studentNameParts = studentName.Split(
    new char[] { ' ' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string firstName = studentNameParts[0];
string lastName = studentNameParts[studentNameParts.Length - 1];
string midName = studentName.Substring
(
    firstName.Length,
    studentName.Length - (firstName.Length + lastName.Length)
).Trim();


firstxt.Text = firstName;
midtext.Text = midName;
Lasttext.Text = lastName;
```